# copy two arrays of int to one char* in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, copy

I have to arrays of int for example `arr1={0,1,1,0,0}`, `arr2={1,0,1,1,1}` and I need to return 1 char* created by `malloc` that will be shown like this : `"01100,10111"`.
when I do for loop it doesn't work, how can I do it ?

```
char* ans = (char*)malloc((size * 2+1) * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ans[i] = first[i];
ans[size] = ",";
for (int i = size+1; i < 2*size+1; i++)
    ans[i] = second[i];
```

Comment: 2nd loop should go from `0` to `size` just like the first to properly index into `second`. Adjust indexing `ans` with `ans[size + 1 + i] = second[i];`. Also if you're going to treat `ans` as a string you need to add a zero terminator.

Comment: Adding fuel to the fire, `ans[size] = ","` had better be puking at least a compiler warning (assignment of pointer to `char`), or you need to turn up your compiler warning levels. And those assigned values should be offset by `'0'`, assuming you actually fix the indexing issues.

Comment: `ans[i] = ","` is wrong.  You can store the integer `0` in a char, but it will not display as `0` when you try to use printf to print it.  Show us the code where you print `ans`.  That is (likely) where the problem is.  If you're doing `printf("%s\n", ans)`, that will not work.

Comment: As others also have pointed, the provided code is a little too less to solve your problems in total. What exactly is the declaration and definition for `size`,`first` and `second`?

Answer (score 1):

Among the multitude of problems:

- Your allocation size is wrong. It should include space for the separating comma *and* the terminating nullchar. `sizeof(int)` is wrong regardless, it should be `sizeof(char)` and as-such can be omitted (`sizeof(char)` is always `1`).
- Your storage is wrong. You want to store characters, and your values should be adjusted relative to `'0'`.
- Your indexing of the second loop is wrong.

In reality, you don't need the second loop in the first place:

```
char* ans = malloc(size * 2 + 2);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    ans[i] = '0' + first[i];
    ans[size+1+i] = '0' + second[i];
}
ans[size] = ',';
ans[2*size+1] = 0;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least four issues with your code.

1. You `malloc` the wrong size, you want to use `sizeof(char)`.
2. You need to zero terminate it, so you need to add extra room for the terminating zero

```
char* ans = (char*)malloc((size * 2+2) * sizeof(char));
second[size * 2+1] = 0;
```

3. Also the indexing of the second loop is wrong. You are accessing second array out of bounds. Make the loop more like the first.
4. We also need to convert the `integer` value to a `char` in the loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ans[size+i+1] = second[i] + '0';
```

Comment: Also the indexing in the second loop. The `malloc` doesn't need sizeof int either. The proper integer to character digit is also required

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
 char* ans = (char*)malloc((size * 2+1) * sizeof(int));
```

- What is `size` here? It is not defined and declared in the provided code.
- You do not need to cast the return value of malloc() to char. In fact, you do not need to cast the return value of malloc() anymore. It is a habit from the early C days.
- Why do you need a char pointer here at all exactly? If you want to print `01100,10111` there is no need to use a char pointer for the output of the integer values.

2.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ans[i] = first[i];
```

- Again what is `size` here?
- What is `first` here? If it isn´t a pointer this statement is invalid.

3.

```
    ans[size] = ",";
```

- This operation is invalid. You are trying to assign a string to a pointer.
- By the way, I don´t know what you trying to do with this statement. You can incorporate the comma separate in the output of `01100,10111`, without your intend to include it int the memory of the int arrays itself.

4.

```
for (int i = size+1; i < 2*size+1; i++)
    ans[i] = second[i];
```

- Same as above: What is value and the type of `size`?
- What is `second`? If it isn´t it a pointer this statement is invalid.

5.

To answer to the question title:

#### (How to) Copy two arrays of int to one char* in C

This isn´t possible. You can´t copy two arrays with its data to a pointer to char.